# java.lang.illegalargumentexception:cannot set a null TableModel

Tags: java, mysql, swing, exception, jtable

I have made a jframe where i have to provide the medicine name and manufacturer name,,then click the search button..
and it will fetch the data from the mysql database and show in the jtable.
the jframe looks like this:
[image]

but when i am giving only medicine name and clicking search button.its not fetching the data ,its just fetching the column names from the database..:
[image]

and when i am giving both the values its giving  :java.lang.illegalargumentexception:cannot set a null TableModel:
[image]

My srch_btnActionPerformed method is:

```
private void srch_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)         {                                         
// TODO add your handling code here:
/*if((jTextField1.getText())!=null || (jTextField2.getText())!=null)
{*/
String sql="select * from medicine where med_name=? or manufacturer_name=?";
try{
pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
pst.setString(2,jTextField2.getText());
rs=pst.executeQuery();


if(rs.next()){
jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

}
else 
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No entry with such names in DataBase!");
jTextField1.setText(null);
jTextField2.setText(null);
}

}
catch(Exception e)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);

}

/* */
}
```

Please help..

Comment: Debug your DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs) to see if it returns not-null value

Comment: this is the debug:                                                                   Have no file for /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/netx.jar
Have no file for /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/plugin.jar
Have no file for /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/jfr.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

//Global Declaration

```
private Vector<Vector<String>> data; //used for data from database
private Vector<String> header; //used to store data header
```

//Display only header on form load

```
//create header for the table
header = new Vector<String>();
header.add("Column1"); 
header.add("Column2");
...
model=new DefaultTableModel(data,header);
table = new JTable(model);
```

//in actionPerformed()

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    if(ae.getSource()==search){
data=get();

        for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        Object[] d={data.get(i).get(0),data.get(i).get(1),data.get(i).get(2)};
        model.addRow(d);
}
}
    }
```

This will help you to get data from database

```
get(){
Vector<Vector<String>> doublevector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

Connection conn = dbConnection();//Your Database connection code
PreparedStatement pre1 = conn.prepareStatement("select * from Table");

ResultSet rs1 = pre1.executeQuery();
while(rs1.next())
{
Vector<String> singlevector = new Vector<String>();
singlevector.add(rs1.getString(1)); 
singlevector.add(rs1.getString(2)); 
....
doublevector.add(singlevector);
}

return doublevector;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass null in your sql query,
You can replace

```
pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
pst.setString(2,jTextField2.getText());
```

by following code:

```
if ( jTextField1.getText() == null)
    pst.setNull(1, Types.VARCHAR);
else
    pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());

if ( jTextField2.getText() == null)
    pst.setNull(2, Types.VARCHAR);
else
    pst.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
```

Comment: how to write the codes fto get the data in jtable by running where clause query .. bcause whenever m doin so its not giving me any data in the jtable..its just showing the column names.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can fix it.... in your database dont set null values for date add dates then this will be ok if there is any other that you didnt specifically mentioned length of the type those attributes also cannot be the null